# Titanium - Label on Map Pin

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-widgets

I need to code for label on the map as product price in Titanium SDK.
Anybody have any idea how to achieve this ?

Waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

What i get from your question is that when you click on a map marker ( product in your case ) , you what to show price of that item as an info window ( for that marker ).

If this is the case then set [title](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Annotation-property-title) of your [annotation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Annotation) as the product price.

Something like ( example taken from [titanium docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Map)) :

```
var Map = require('ti.map'); //extend map global object
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

var mountainView = Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters", //<--------- YOUR PRODUCT PRICE HERE
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    myid:1 // Custom property to uniquely identify this annotation.
});

var mapview = Map.createView({
    mapType: Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993,
            latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[mountainView]
});

win.add(mapview);
// Handle click events on any annotations on this map.
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    Ti.API.info("Annotation " + evt.title + " clicked, id: " + evt.annotation.myid);
});
win.open();
```